# Passing array as list of arguments to a non user defined function

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently writing a very basic PHP api which uses MySql databases for authentication and logging user data. I use prepared statements to avoid MySql injection. I attempted to make a generic function to handle and execute prepared queries as follows:

```
function query_prepared($sql, $type){//$type here is the string containing the characters of the type of the data to bind - e.g. 'sss' for string, string, string
    $args = func_get_args();
    $param_args = array();
    for($i = 2; $i < count($args); $i++){
        $param_args[$i - 2] = $args[$i];
    }//the version of PHP I am using does not support variable length arguments so I have to store all of the arguments but the sql statement and parameter types in an array ($param_args)
    $con = connect();//connects to the database
    $statement = $con->prepare($sql);
    if(!$statement)
        error("Error while querying database. " . mysqli_error($con), ERR_QUERY_DB);
    $statement->bind_param($type, $param_args);//<-- My problem is here - the bind_param function is supposed to pass arguments like this, $statement->bind_param($type, $var0, $var1, $var2...) but I only have an array of $var0, $var1, $var2... so it attempts to convert my array to a string before passing it to the bind_param function.
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($result);
    $rows = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $result->fetch())
        $rows[$i++] = $row;
    $con->close();
    return $rows;
}
```

I have done some reading and found the `call_user_func_array` function but this obviously will not work in this instance.

Is there any way of passing my array ($param_args) as a variable length argument to the bind_params function.

Comment: Your array should be an associative like `':param' => 'value'`

Comment: What do you mean by "*obviously* will not work in this instance"?

Comment: @AlanMachado how can I do that?

Comment: @RocketHazmat How would you use it in this case?

Comment: @AlanMachado: That only works with PDO.  This is using MySQLi.

Comment: @rodit: Check my answer.

Comment: @RocketHazmat oh yes you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/call_user_func_array) here.  In fact, that's the correct way to do this.

```
array_unshift($param_args, $type);  // <- Prepend $type to the array so it's passed too
// The 1st parameter is the callback.  It's array($object, 'method')
call_user_func_array(array($statement, 'bind_param'), $param_args);
```

NOTE: `bind_param` wants the args to be *references*, you'll have to tweak how you're setting `$param_args`:

```
for($i = 2; $i < count($args); $i++){
    $param_args[] =& $args[$i];
}
```